# How do I limit the word count in a text box in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to set up text boxes on a form in Microsoft Word, with a word count limit, not a character limit.

The limit should be for each box **not** the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

#### I need to set up boxes on a form in Microsoft word with a word count limit

- Set a Validation Rule for the field (textbox).
- In the condition select the "The expression" and type the below condition

  ```
  string-length(field)-string-length(translate(field," ","")) <10
  ```

Notes:

- `10` is the limit. Modify as necessary for your circumstances.
- `field` is the name of the textbox.
- Enter the text in the Screen Tip (eg "Please enter fewer than 10 words") and click the more option if you want a ScreenTip and dialog box message.
- To testing in the preview type more then 10 words and hit tab, a dialog box with "Please enter fewer than 10 words" will appear.

Source [Limit number of words in the text box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31058636/3536342) by [trx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2698249/trx)